# Impressão com MPTPrinter

Tags: totalcross

Bom dia, preciso fazer uma impressão usando o MPTPrinter. Porem essa impressão precisa ter um certo alinhamento, por exemplo os valores precisam ser impressos da direita para esquerda.
Porem quando uso o comando setHorizontalAlignment(Control.RIGHT) fica totalmente alinhado a direita do papel, e preciso imprimir 3 informações alinhadas da direta para esquerda na mesma linha (informações de Valores).
Gostaria de saber como faço esse tipo de alinhamento, quais comandos posso usar?

Segue o código de teste (apenas um teste da impressão dos itens do pedido).

```
protected void imprimirItensNota(NotaFiscal nota){
    try {

        mPrinter.setFont(true, false, false, false);

        mPrinter.setXPos(1);
        mPrinter.print("Produto");

        mPrinter.setXPos(270);
        mPrinter.print("Qtde.");

        mPrinter.setXPos(360);
        mPrinter.print("Unit.");

        mPrinter.setXPos(440);
        mPrinter.print("Desc.");

        mPrinter.setXPos(510);
        mPrinter.print("Total");

        mPrinter.newLine();         

        for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
            mPrinter.setXPos(1);
            mPrinter.print("Produto de teste");

            mPrinter.setXPos(255);
            mPrinter.print("250,00");

            mPrinter.setXPos(350);
            mPrinter.print("999,99");

            mPrinter.setXPos(430);
            mPrinter.print("999,99");

            mPrinter.setXPos(495);
            mPrinter.print("999,99");
            mPrinter.newLine(1);                
        }           


    } catch (Exception e) {
        MessageBox.showException(e, true);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Seria interessante postar o codigo que esta tentando para nos ajudar tambem

Comment: Uma alternativa para isso seria fazendo space-padding. Você tentou fazer alternância do alinhamento horizontal? Tipo, `alinhamento esquerda` => `texto informativo` => `alinhamento direita` => `texto valor`?

Comment: Bom dia Jefferson, vc teria algum exemplo para me passar?

Comment: Como eu faço para tratar as palavras com acentuação?  as palavras que contem "ç" ou "ã", estão saindo com um caractere muito estranho.

Comment: Outra alternativa seria criar uma imagem e imprimir a imagem por meio do MPTPrinter... é só utilizar o MonoImage, capturar o graphcs do mesmo (monoImage.getGraphics()) e "desenhar"  sua impressão no graphics, com isto consegui utilizar acentuação sem problemas e para alinhamento você pode fazer facilmente por calculo